# Property content is set more than once

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I would like to have text block and hyperlink button in one scrollviewer, but it says property content is set more than once...

```
        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,15,0,85" Width="460" Height="1500" Name="TextBlock1" TextWrapping="Wrap"> 
            <LineBreak />
        <Run FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="27" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline">
           Weider 6 pack Training is a perfect exercise for flat stomach. 
            </Run>
            <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="This easy training programme has many advantages." FontSize="27" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="1. It's perfect for beginners and for experts" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="27" />
        <Run Text=" – exercises are easy and begin with the basic level, so every beginner can use them but they get more complicated pretty fast so advanced sportsmen can also be interested in them." FontSize="27" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="2.It helps not only carve your muscles but also burn fat" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="27" />
        <Run Text=" – during the exercise you not only use your abdominal rectus but you also move your legs and arms. It is also because W6 puts pressure on the number of repetitions. It carves your muscles but also burns fat. You can train W6 for about 40 minutes without taking any breaks – you use up all glycogen in blood and start burning the fat." FontSize="27" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="3.It is easy " FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="27" />
        <Run Text="– it is a really easy training set which you can train almost anywhere. All you need is flat ground." FontSize="27" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="4.It gives excellent results" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="27" />
        <Run Text=" – if you want to have a flat stomach W6 is designed just for you. You can see the first effects after just a week and after a whole series it is really impressive." FontSize="27" />"
        <LineBreak />
                </TextBlock>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="HyperlinkButton" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,489,0,0" Name="HyperlinkButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have two controls in your ScrollViewer : Textblock and HyperlinkButton. Group them into a Grid.

Comment: What do u mean by group into a grid??

Comment: <ScrollViewer>
<Grid>
<TextBlock/><HyperlinkButton /></Grid></ScrollViewer>

Comment: @dawid lis you put a control around it (for example a grid or stack panel) so it's only 1 item. In Blend you have a menu called "group into" that can do this for you.

Comment: anyone knows why when i scroll down it scrolls only some part of content panel, and when i release click it goes back?

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap it in a `StackPanel` or a `Grid`. That way, you can still set the `Content` property once, but have multiple items in it.